# How to show ajax result on dynamically created id selector?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using 10 `<div>` with `class='ThisOne'` using my PHP code -

```
<?php      
for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) {
?>
<div id="">
    <input type="text" id="GetCommentText-<?php echo $i;?>"></input>
    <input type="hidden" id="GetPostID-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $i;?>"></input>
    <button type="button" id="SelectPostComment-<?php echo $i;?>" data-target="<?php echo $i;?>" >Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="ShowAjaxesult-<?php echo $i;?>" class="Thisone" style="" ></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I want to expand `<div>` with `id="ShowAjaxesult-5"` when user click on `<button>` with `id="SelectPostComment-5"`. Similarly expand `<div>` with `id="ShowAjaxesult-8"` when user click on `<button>` with `id="SelectPostComment-8"` and so on.

For this JS that I'm using looks like -

```
           <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $("[id^=SelectPostComment-]").click(function(){
                   var $Parent = $(this).parent();
                   var CommentText = $Parent.find('[id^="GetCommentText-"]:first').val();
                    var PostID = $Parent.find('[id^="GetPostID-"]:first').val();

                   $.ajax( {
                      type : 'GET',
                      url:'test1.php',
                      data : {CommentText: CommentText, PostID: PostID},
                      success:function(data) {                               
                       $("[id^=ShowAjaxesult-]").html(data);
                      }
                   });
               });
            });
            </script>
```

Problem with the above code is that when i click on any `<button>` it display all `<div>` ( all `<div>` with `ShowAjaxesult-1` and `ShowAjaxesult-2` and .... `ShowAjaxesult-10` ). I want to display one `<div>` on every `<button>` click depending on value of it's `id` selector. For eg display `<div id='ShowAjaxesult-2'>` on selecting `<button id='SelectPostComment-2'>` and so on. Not sure what mistake I'm making. Please help.

Comment: are `CommentText` and `PostID` the correct and expected values?

Comment: @Pankrates Yes. I'm getting correct values of both CommentText and PostID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your buttons and inputs and you can do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".subBtn").click(function(){
           var $Parent = $(this).parent();
           var CommentText = $Parent.find('.getComment').val();
            var PostID = $Parent.find('.getPost').val();

           $.ajax( {
              type : 'GET',
              url:'test1.php',
              data : {CommentText: CommentText, PostID: PostID},
              success:function(data) {                               
               $Parent.next().html(data);
              }
           });
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing

```
                   $("[id^=ShowAjaxesult-]").html(data);
```

Into:

```
                   $("#ShowAjaxesult-"+PostID).html(data);
```

Made it work for me.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me too. But using class selectors for this will be better as @realseanp has suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the id^= syntax but your selector is not specific enough. You can get the index from your button's id like this:

```
var i = $(this).split('-')[1];
```

Then append it to your ajax results div like this:

```
$("[id=ShowAjaxesult-"+i+"]").html(data);
```

On a side note I find using "$Parent" as a variable name disturbing. Are you simply mixing PHP syntax here or is there some significance adding a dollar sign to the front and making the first letter uppercase?

Cheers,

Jesse